# ArcadeDB | `All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions. Check the error log to find the actual reason.`

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, graph-traversal, remote-connection, arcadedb

## What are the details of your problem?

Why is Tinkerpop-Gremlin `AnonymousTraversalSource` finding ArcadeDB unavailable?

I looked at `log/arcadedb.log.x` files but they're empty.
And the Log4j2 logs also don't contain any further information.
I may just not be putting in the right keywords and/or phrasing in internet-searches and AI for help.

```js
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnectionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions. Check the error log to find the actual reason.
...
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnectionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions. Check the error log to find the actual reason.
```

I know this is a newbie question. I just can't quite connect-the-dots on converting this.
Maybe its already in the docs but I misunderstood or didn't realize what its saying was what I was looking for.
I just don't have the experience nor fully fleshed out examples to learn from yet.

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

I can get vertex and edges made with the fixed example of the ArcadeDB docs.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
        DatabaseFactory databaseFactory = new DatabaseFactory("/databases/mydb");
        Database database = databaseFactory.open();
        database.begin();
//        database.command("sql", "create vertex type User");
//        MutableVertex elon = db.newVertex("User", "name", "Elon", "lastName", "Musk");
        MutableVertex elon = database.newVertex("User");
        elon.set("name", "Elon").set("lastName", "Musk").save();
//        MutableVertex steve = db.newVertex("User", "name", "Steve", "lastName", "Jobs");
        MutableVertex steve = database.newVertex("User");
        steve.set("name", "Steve").set("lastName", "Jobs").save();
//        database.command("sql", "create edge type IsFriendOf");
        elon.newEdge("IsFriendOf", steve, true, "since", 2010);
        database.commit();
        database.close();
    }
```

Now I just want to switch this to Tinkerpop-Gremlin's to be more standard as I'm testing-and-comparing graph-databases (GDBs).
I'm already having a learning curve just getting reproducible examples and adjustment-tweaks between the GDBs since I haven't experienced everything being exactly 1-2-1.
But, I can't even seem to connect with `DriverRemoteConnection` to the (ArcadeDB-Plugin?) Gremlin-Server(?).
I've tried to use different ports in-case I misread or the documents weren't updated to the latest setup.
But that didn't work this time.

#### Error Output

```js
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnectionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions. Check the error log to find the actual reason.
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.promise(RemoteStep.java:97)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.processNextStart(RemoteStep.java:65)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:135)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:40)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:249)
        ...
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnectionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions. Check the error log to find the actual reason.
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection.submitAsync(DriverRemoteConnection.java:231)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.promise(RemoteStep.java:89)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions. Check the error log to find the actual reason.
```

#### Only two lines of code

```java
        GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using("localhost", 8182, "g"));
        logger.info(g.V().next());
```

#### Deployment script for ArcadeDB-Gremlin-Docker container

```js
docker run -d -p 2480:2480 -p 2424:2424 -p 6379:6379 -p 5432:5432 -p 8182:8182
    --env JAVA_OPTS="-Darcadedb.server.rootPassword=playwithdata -Darcadedb.server.defaultDatabases=Imported[root]{import:https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb-datasets/raw/main/orientdb/OpenBeer.gz} 
    -Darcadedb.server.plugins=Redis:com.arcadedb.redis.RedisProtocolPlugin,MongoDB:com.arcadedb.mongo.MongoDBProtocolPlugin,Postgres:com.arcadedb.postgres.PostgresProtocolPlugin,GremlinServer:com.arcadedb.server.gremlin.GremlinServerPlugin" 
    arcadedata/arcadedb
```

What additional step did I miss reading or misread?